# Setting up a Python server with Angularjs app and capture user input

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, web, server

Is it possible to help me please, just a hint or a useful tip if you know something better than this approach.

I've developed a list of forms with HTML and AngularJS, that for each form when the users submits, the input data is collected into a stack of json-string data.

I'm looking for a way to:

- post this data in a python server
- process it with python code
- render the result on the page (view)

I set up a Flask server and it does just print the html without binding with AngularJs. When I tried to set it up with SimpleHttp python command it worked (but I don't know if it is possible to manipulate the data ?)

Thanks for your attention, and sorry if it not concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good practice to seperate the server that serves your web client (angular) and the server that serves as your API (flask). I would recommend using a simple server like [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/) to serve your angular app. You will basically have a folder that contains your web app files, and it will serve them via GET requests.

Your flask server should operate independently of your web app. For your flask app, you'll want to create a route `@app.route('/api/myPostData/')` for your web app to use. The angular app will send a HTTP request to the flask server (you will need to specify the host, url, and port). Once the request is finished, you can use something like `$scope.watch()` in angular to update your page.

This approach is more complex than serving the angular app from flask, but I think it's the best approach. I've set up flask apps to serve both static files and act as an API, and I have found that it's not a good way to structure the project. Also I don't enjoy working with static files in flask, but that's my personal opinion. Happy coding :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is really helpful ! :D
In fact if you're curious, I am coding an editor that generates Python code to create neural networks. The forms are for each type of layer, taking the parameters. The app sends the parameters to the server, and the server generates the Python code (using the Keras library). Thanks another time :)

Comment: Sounds cool. I'm looking for a new project to collaborate on at the moment if you need any help. Let me know and I'll send you my contact info